# How to skip passing context again and again for html canvas while coding

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, 2d, p5.js

I am trying to make something using html canvas but I have to pass context to each function again and again. Is there a way to skip or automate this task somehow?

For example in p5.js we only have
setup and draw functions and no extra context etc..
I want to do the same thing but at a small scale

```
 function render() { 
      console.log(data)
      // i have to pass context again and again to each function 
      drawPoint(context, new Vector(mousex, mousey), 6)
      drawPoint(context, new Vector(100, 100), 5, "red")
      drawPoint(context, new Vector(100, 100), 5, "red")
      drawPoint(context, new Vector(100, 100), 5, "red")
      drawPoint(context, new Vector(100, 100), 5, "red")
      requestAnimationFrame(render)
    }
    render()
```

I want it to be like

```
function start(){
  // some global variables that may be accessed in 
  // the render function directly

}
function render(){
 // some code without passing any context
 drawpoint(new Vector(100, 100))

}
```

**In simple words I just want to mimic the same effect as the p5.js processing, or arduino ide etc..**
just two functions one for setup and one for loop

Does someone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a higher-order function to basically give the context once, then just call that function repeatedly.

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function createDrawPoint(context) {
  return (vector) => {
    console.log('drawPoint called with context', vector);
    // do something with context here
  };
}

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const drawPoint = createDrawPoint(context);
drawPoint(new Vector(100, 100));
drawPoint(new Vector(100, 150));
drawPoint(new Vector(150, 100));
```

Basically, you create a function that'll return the actual `drawPoint()` function, but with `context` bound within its scope, so you don't have to pass it in repeatedly.

You could do the same with multiple methods as well, if you wanted, like this.

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function createDrawPoint(context) {
  return {
    drawPoint: (vector) => {
      console.log('drawPoint called with context', vector);
      // do something with context here
    },
    drawLine: (vectorA, vectorB) => {
      console.log('drawLine called with context', vector);
    }
  };
}

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const { drawPoint, drawLine } = createDrawPoint(context);

drawPoint(new Vector(100, 100));
drawPoint(new Vector(100, 150));
drawPoint(new Vector(150, 100));
drawLine(new Vector(200, 200), new Vector(300, 300));
```

Though if you have multiple I would probably group them into a class (or just an protoypal object constructor if you don't like the class syntax for some reason), unless this program literally only uses these functions.

```js
class DrawHelper {
  constructor(context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  
  drawPoint(vector) {
    console.log('drawPoint');
  }
  
  drawLine(a, b) {
    console.log('drawLine');
  }
}

class Vector {}

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const drawHelper = new DrawHelper(context);

drawHelper.drawPoint(new Vector(100, 100));
drawHelper.drawPoint(new Vector(100, 200));

drawHelper.drawLine(new Vector(300, 300), new Vector(400, 400));
```

Comment: Okey.. even though it is enough. I want know that if there is a way if I handle all these tasks that you are telling in back-end and show the user only setup(){} and draw(){} functions like in p5.js.. as shown here : [click here https://editor.p5js.org/](https://editor.p5js.org/) , please tell me if you have, It will save my time a lot.

Comment: I updated my code snippet to do multiple methods. If you want to have that done in `setup()`, just declare the function variables (`drawPoint()`, etc.) in the global scope, then assign them in `setup()`, then call them in `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

make your own function?

```js
function myDrawPoint  () {
    drawPoint.apply(null, [context, ...Object.values(arguments)]);
}
```

Comment: Can You explain it a bit more.. 1 code segment is not enough for me..

Comment: I will give BAT as a reward

Comment: use the new function `myDrawPoint` instead of `drawPoint`. it is basically the old function without the context